# Change starting position in integer list android

Tags: android, list, integer

I made an Integer list comprised of words located in a strings.xml file.

```
 // Animal Word List//
 Integer[] stringIdList = {R.string.text1, R.string.text2, R.string.text3, R.string.text4, R.string.text5, R.string.text6, R.string.text7,
        R.string.text8, R.string.text9, R.string.text10, R.string.text11, R.string.text12, R.string.text13, R.string.text14, R.string.text15,
        R.string.text16, R.string.text17, R.string.text18, R.string.text19, R.string.text20, R.string.text21, R.string.text22, R.string.text23,
        R.string.text24, R.string.text25, R.string.text26, R.string.text27, R.string.text28, R.string.text29, R.string.text30, R.string.text31,
        R.string.text32, R.string.text33, R.string.text34, R.string.text35, R.string.text36, R.string.text37, R.string.text38, R.string.text39,
        R.string.text40, R.string.text41, R.string.text42, R.string.text43, R.string.text44, R.string.text45, R.string.text46, R.string.text47,
        R.string.text48, R.string.text49, R.string.text50, R.string.text51, R.string.text52, R.string.text53, R.string.text54, R.string.text55,
        R.string.text56, R.string.text57, R.string.text58, R.string.text59, R.string.text60, R.string.text61, R.string.text62, R.string.text63,
        R.string.text64, R.string.text65, R.string.text66, R.string.text67, R.string.text68, R.string.text69, R.string.text70, R.string.text71,
        R.string.text72, R.string.text73, R.string.text74, R.string.text75, R.string.text76, R.string.text77, R.string.text78, R.string.text79,
        R.string.text80, R.string.text81, R.string.text82, R.string.text83, R.string.text84, R.string.text85, R.string.text86, R.string.text87,
        R.string.text88, R.string.text89, R.string.text90, R.string.text91, R.string.text92, R.string.text93, R.string.text94, R.string.text95,
        R.string.text96, R.string.text97, R.string.text98, R.string.text99, R.string.text100};
```

By default it starts with 0 and goes up to 100 using

```
// Where List Starts//
int stringListCounter = 0;
```

where 0 is the beginning of the list. I switch between each number by clicking button next which containes

```
            // Repeat Words//               
            if (word.getText().toString().equals("Big Foot")) {

                stringListCounter = 0;

            }

               // Change To Next Word//
               stringListCounter++;
               word.setText(stringIdList[stringListCounter]);
```

Every time I enter this activity I want the starting number to be randomly changed. For instance I open animals.class activity and stringListCounter = 0; I exit out of the activity then go back in and its now stringListCounter = 43; Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a random number in your lifecycle method and set it to `stringListCounter`

```
public class AnimalActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         super.onResume();
         stringListCounter = randInt(0,100);
     }

     private int randInt(int min, int max) {
         Random rand = new Random();
         int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

         return randomNum;
     }
}
```

Comment: With this the number will change every time a dialog is shown and dismissed. It should happen in the onCreate method.

Comment: `onCreate` or `onStart` are good candidates. Research the [Android Lifecyle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) to find what fits your needs best